# Why is Copy+Paste of text a once only operation - I have to keep Copying for the next paste

Tags: copy-paste, samsung-galaxy-a5

As per the title, I used to have an Android (v5) where I would copy some text once, and keep pasting to wherever;

On my new phone (Android v10 - Samsung Galaxy A51), clipboard text disappears after a paste; Is there a setting to allow retaining last copied text ?

[cannot create samsung-galaxy-a51 so using samsung-galaxy-a5 instead]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although Android itself shouldn't be rule out, you should first check the issue is not related to your keyboard. If possible, try to install another keyboard app for example GBoard. Set it as the default keyboard app, enable its clipboard, then try to copy and paste. Verify if the problem persists or not.